# Wordpress migration issue. Warning: PHP Startup: Expected parameter 1 to be an array, bool given in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, collation, formidable

I have encountered an issue while migrating my wordpress from localhost to the server. Below, there is a short explanation where was the problem and what I have tried to solve it (step by step). Unfortunately it is still not working.

**1. When loading new database I have received an error like below:**

```
#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

My solution to that was replacing unknown collation to "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci" which is used by the other tables.

**2. After doing above, database has loaded without errors, but the most important thing on the landing page has crashed. Where the FORM is placed, there is a bunch of warnings:**

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Expected parameter 1 to be an array, bool given in /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/formidable/classes/helpers/FrmEntriesHelper.php on line 37
```

Here is the function where the line 37 was prompted as wrong:

```
public static function setup_new_vars( $fields, $form = '', $reset = false, $args = array() ) {
        remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'FrmFormsController::insert_form_button' );

        $values = array(
            'name'        => '',
            'description' => '',
            'item_key'    => '',
        );

        $values['fields'] = array();
        if ( empty( $fields ) ) {
            return apply_filters( 'frm_setup_new_entry', $values );
        }

        foreach ( (array) $fields as $field ) {
            $original_default = $field->default_value;
            self::prepare_field_default_value( $field );
            $new_value = self::get_field_value_for_new_entry( $field, $reset, $args );

            $field_array                     = FrmAppHelper::start_field_array( $field );
            $field_array['value']            = $new_value;
            $field_array['type']             = apply_filters( 'frm_field_type', $field->type, $field, $new_value );
            $field_array['parent_form_id']   = isset( $args['parent_form_id'] ) ? $args['parent_form_id'] : $field->form_id;
            $field_array['reset_value']      = $reset;
            $field_array['in_embed_form']    = isset( $args['in_embed_form'] ) ? $args['in_embed_form'] : '0';
            $field_array['original_default'] = $original_default;

            FrmFieldsHelper::prepare_new_front_field( $field_array, $field, $args );

            $field_array = array_merge( $field->field_options, $field_array );

            $values['fields'][] = $field_array;

            if ( ! $form || ! isset( $form->id ) ) {
                $form = FrmForm::getOne( $field->form_id );
            }
        }

        FrmAppHelper::unserialize_or_decode( $form->options );
        if ( is_array( $form->options ) ) {
            $values = array_merge( $values, $form->options );
        }

        $form_defaults                 = FrmFormsHelper::get_default_opts();
        $form_defaults['custom_style'] = FrmAppHelper::custom_style_value( array() );

        $values = array_merge( $form_defaults, $values );

        return apply_filters( 'frm_setup_new_entry', $values );
    }
```

Line 37:

```
$field_array = array_merge( $field->field_options, $field_array );
```

This issue causes that some of the inputs that should be seen in the form are not displayed. Does anyone of you went through something similar?

Locally I got Mysql 8 installed, on there server there is Mysql 5.6 without possibility to upgrade.

Comment: Why not use the **same** MySQL server version on both systems? Also, if there is any PHP error like this, why not resolve it? There are tons of questions handling `Expected parameter 1 to be an array, bool given`

Comment: I am not PHP programmer, I just wanted to launch simple wordpress website. Unfortunately I have not find exact answer to the problem I have encounter...

Comment: If you are facing a problem with a Wordpress plugin you are using, you need to contact the maintainers of that plugin